# Ionic framework new Ionic Slides based on the Swiper widget from idangerous: how to change slide after button ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Reference Link: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/

I would like to make slide forward or backward after click on the previous or next button.

I have working example for swipe gesture [Codepen](http://codepen.io/thenappanz/pen/oLyqWN).

how can I do it for button click?

```
$scope.slidePrevious = function() {

}

$scope.slideNext = function() {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this into your click handlers, it'll do the job

```
$scope.slidePrevious = function() {
    $scope.data.sliderDelegate.slidePrev();
}

$scope.slideNext = function() {
    $scope.data.sliderDelegate.slideNext();
}
```

Here is updated codePen
http://codepen.io/kmlzjc/pen/rLKdbR

Comment: You can also alter the speed of animation like this
`$scope.data.sliderDelegate.slidePrev(undefined, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

Would you like the animation to happen as well?

If you don't need that, you could just put it in a common method and do this:

```
function slideEnd() {
          $scope.data.currentPage = $scope.data.sliderDelegate.activeIndex;
          //use $scope.$apply() to refresh any content external to the slider
          $scope.$apply();
}

$scope.data.sliderDelegate.on('slideChangeEnd', slideEnd);
$scope.slideNext = slideEnd;
```

Comment: i tried it is not working. In my working example from codepen when swipe to right it changes to next slide. I need the same functionality when next button is pressed.